# Filter django query set based on whether a foreign key relationship exists

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys, django-queryset

So I have two models.

```
class Post(models.Model): 
    id = models.OidField('object id', unique=True)

class ArchivedFlag(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(post,
                         on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                         related_name='archived_flag')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,
                         on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                         related_name='archives')
```

In views.py I have generated a list of all posts by some criteria, 'plist'.

I want to filter the list based on posts that DO NOT have an ArchivedFlag object relationship. Basically the ArchivedFlag model is a tool hide certain posts.

How can I do this? I'm trying to do something along the lines of

```
plist = plist.exclude(models.ForeignKey.Post exists)
```

but I'm unsure of the exact syntax.

Comment: How does the `Commit` relates to the `Post`? Has the `Commit` object a `ForeignKey` to the `Post`? Can you include the (relevant parts of the ) `Commit` model?

Comment: Oh whoops, I just updated it, that was a typo. The relationship is only between Post and ArchivedFlag

Answer (score 3):

You can exclude `Post` objects for which an`ArchivedFlag` exists with:

```
Post.objects.exclude(archived_flag__isnull=False)
```

or easier with a simple filter:

```
Post.objects.filter(archived_flag=None)
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Comment: Great thank you! Follow up question, what if I only want this filter to apply when the current user is the user on the archived flag?

Comment: @sdaniele: then you filter with `Post.objects.exclude(archived_flag__user=request.user, archived_flag__isnull=False)`

Comment: So you can just add exclude parameters comma separated in an and sort of fashion?

Comment: @sdaniele: yes, probably you can even drop the `archived_flag__isnull=False`, since that is implied by the fact that the `user=request.user`, so `Post.objects.exclude(archived_flag__user=request.user)` is likely sufficient here.